# Logging in to website from android app to retrieve and parse information

Tags: java, android, networking

I've been researching networking in android and have become familiar with the basic concepts. However, I've recently been working on an app intended for use by my school as a gradebook/assignment display of sorts. My school uses the following online gradebook: https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/, and currently I'm trying to allow students to input their login credentials into my app which will then try to retrieve their respective information and display it in a gridview. However, I have never attempted to log in to a website from an android app before parsing data (I have gone through several similar questions but I am still a little confused)

Any help is appreciated!

[edit] After logging in I will use import.io to display gradebook data, website does not have api

Comment: I'm assuming they don't have an API, so I'd use the `JSoup` library. It can log in, retrieve the cookies, and you can then easily parse the data. After that you can just put it in a `GridView`.

Comment: There is a link [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/) which might answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand You clearly  u need to :

1. Connect to  site using HttpURLConnection with  user creditentials (do Post request to login page)
2. Obtain cookies from request (my favorite way is to parse -  copy appropriate header field)
3. Use obtained cookies with HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",obtainedCookies) and do another request(to user data page).
4. Get input stream
5. Parse stream 
   (to obtain Document  "html"  u can use jsoup example:
   Document doc = JSoup.parse(stream, null, "");
6. Show data

> **GUIDELINES:**
>
> [cookie how to](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)
>
> **[Most useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/4669617)**

Caution:

-any http requests needs to be done outside main thread (ui thread)   -  u can use async task for this or intent service

**EDIT** on questions:

you ask **whether to use Jsoup to handle connection?**

**my answer is NO!**

Jsoup is a PARSER by using HttpURLConnection u **gain full control over HTTP request** so for example u can handle some specyfic exceptions or request propertiers which jsoup is not capable! from my experience after a while I start to disassemble the libraries and learn from them the basics and use parts of them in my code!

Comment: would you recommend using HttpUrlConnection rather than JSoup throughout?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have not done much networking previous to this so I wrote some code in Java to practice before adding it to android, but I still don't really understand the concept of submitting and taking data programmatically...My code is here: http://bit.ly/1D1MHWy

Comment: in hurry for u -> this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629938/need-help-logging-into-website-and-retrieving-information/31630379#31630379 if u will have other question i can answer it later now im going out :D

Answer (score 0):

You could make a WebView with a custom HTML file which has a login and password field, and then have the HTML file run the same script as the website to log them in.

Comment: Trying not to resort to WebViews and instead just have them input credentials locally and have the app log them in through the background thread